# Execution plan tab not appearing in MySQL Workbench 6.1.7

Tags: mysql, ubuntu-14.04, mysql-workbench, database-performance

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.3 LTS and i have mysql Ver 14.14 Distrib 5.6.27 for debian-linux-gnu (i686), I have updated MySQL Workbench to version 6.1.7 to use the Performance tools. But When i run a query like this:

```
SELECT * FROM Patient INNER JOIN Department ON
Patient.department_id=Department.id
where Patient.id<100;
```

I don't have the Execution plan tab like in the right lower corner [here](http://wb.fabforce.eu/wp-content/uploads/Screenshot-2014-09-05-14.35.39.png).

I only have the first four tabs, but not the execution plan tab. I have been looking all over and seems nobody has seen this problem before, am i missing something?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The "Execution Plan" tab was [added in Workbench 6.2](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/workbench/en/wb-what-is-new-62.html). You are using WB 6.1, and WB 6.3 is the current version. Please upgrade to the latest version of Workbench.

Use the [official MySQL APT repository](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/repo/apt/) to always use the latest version of MySQL products. After installing the APT repository, install package *mysql-workbench-community* (official) instead of *mysql-workbench* (distro). Or, [download](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/workbench/) and install the latest binary.